# Submodulare welfare maximization: is an additive approximation algorithm known?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization

[Sudmodular welfare maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_maximization#Submodular_agents) is the problem of allocating items among agents with different valuations, represented by submodular set functions, such that the sum of agents' values is as large as possible. There is a 0.5-factor deterministic approximation algorithm, and a ~0.63-factor randomized approximation algorithm.

I am looking for a polynomial-time algorithm with an *additive* approximation guarantee, such as the following: "The welfare of the allocation found by the algorithm is at least as high as the optimal welfare minus the largest marginal value of a single item".

Does anything similar to this exist?